# How to set a RegistryKey Value in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, registerhotkey

I have a Project and i am trying to run the installer on a new pc to test my WPF application, but the registry key is not automatically created. I have tried adding it manually but i don't know why it is not working, i am sure i am not adding the key the right way. Also i am confused since it is a new PC how do i add something that will automatically create a path?
The one that i am creating is something like this in the Image:

[VS Image][1]

[image: My Registery]

Comment: Please provide us a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is when i run my application it does not scans, as it is a scanning app. Because the registry key is not automatically created.

Comment: ScanSnap is a Fujitsu thing - it's not a standard Windows feature. I suggest you browse their site for documentation on how to register an extension.

Answer (score 0):

HKLM -- do you have Admin right? really privileged rights?

How to test that you have enough right to write to HKLM (just call `OpenSubKey`):

```
public bool CanSetRegKeyValue(string path, string valueName, RegistryKey registry = null)
{
    bool result = true;

    try
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = null;

        if (registry == null)
        {
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
        }

        using (RegistryKey key = registryKey.OpenSubKey(path, true))
        {
            result = key != null;
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and usage sample, which checking write ability to Key `DefaultLevel` under node HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\safer\codeidentifiers:

```
bool result = CanSetRegKeyValue("SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\safer\\codeidentifiers\\", "DefaultLevel");
```